# Encrypt SQLite database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, sqlite, encryption

What is the best approach to encrypting a SQLite database file in .Net/C#? I'm using [sqlite-dotnet2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2) wrapper.

There are tools like [SQLite Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) and [SQLite Crypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/), but both are non-free, while my project is under GPL.

The naive approach I thought of using was to let SQLite handle a temporary file, then to encrypt it on program exit, and overwrite (zero-out) the original. The obvious drawback is that if program crashes (and while it is running), the plain text DB is accessible.

Is there a better way to approach this? Can I pass an encrypted stream to the wrapper (instead of using SQLiteConnection.CreateFile) ?

[edit] Maybe I am overthinking this. Is is sufficient to use Password option in the connection string? Would the file be encrypted properly in that case (or is it some weaker protection)?

Comment: > There are tools like SQLite Encryption Extension and SQLite Crypt, but both are non-free, while my project is under GPL.

We haven't tried using it with .NET just yet, but I'm on the development team for [SQLCipher][1], which is basically a free and unencumbered version of SQLite that provides transparent database encryption. I'd recommend it for use in mobile and/or stand-alone application settings where an embedded db is desirable.


  [1]: http://github.com/sjlombardo/sqlcipher

Comment: ...and .NET version of SQLCipher is also now a commercial product :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recommend using the `System.Data.Sqlite` wrapper, which includes encryption. It works great, it's easy to use, and it's a complete ADO.Net implementation. You can get the wrapper from https://system.data.sqlite.org, and the developer describes how to use the encryption on this forum at: https://web.archive.org/web/20100207030625/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/130.aspx. Hint - you just set the password property. He also describes how he does the encryption using the Microsoft Crypto API elsewhere in the forum.

Comment: The links are broken. Could you provide the new one?

Comment: Looks like Robert Simpson abandoned the phxsoftware site once control of the software was transfered to http://system.data.sqlite.org in 2011. I don't think that the old forum pages are posted anywhere else.

Comment: cached version of the above link

http://web.archive.org/web/20130325100811/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/130.aspx

Comment: version 113 did drop support SetPassword. SEE is the new way to go, even thought it does cost 2000$ and requires manual compilation.

Comment: @Bin4ry see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72073407/8586332

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at:

http://zetetic.net/software/sqlcipher

It is open source.

You can chek also the code for the wxsqlite3.

Answer (score 5):

I would try http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/, it's rewrite of SQLite 3.6.16 in C#, under MIT License. I suppose it will be easy to tweak it.

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the note below, it also support **sqlcipher** encryption

**UPDATE:** Since Google Code went read only the project has moved to it's own website https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: C#-SQLite includes built in support for the sqlcipher package;  You compile it with SQLITE_HAS_CODEC and activate it with PRAGMA hexkey="0x0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f10";