# How to encrypt/decrypt data in SQLite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

I'm working on a project and I want to protect information which is in SQLite database. I want to use algorithms such as RC4, DES, AES. I use C#. Please help me!

Comment: In order to be helpful, it helps us to have way more context than that. Can you tell us a little about what you're trying to store in SQLite?

Comment: Just encrypt the data and store it in a blob column. If SQLite doesn't support blobs, encode the encrypted data with base64 and store it in a text field. If you're encrypting the whole thing, you should see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259561/encrypt-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp

Comment: What @Polynomial said is about it. Note that storing **passwords** in a database is a completely different problem and requires cryptographic *hashing* algorithms. You should clarify your question a bit, because security can be rather complex to implement properly, if you have no experience.

Comment: @Groo - Security *is* complex to implement properly, full stop.

Comment: using additional library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259561/encrypt-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp), the easiest way is to use the [System.Data.Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) wrapper and include a password in the connection string. This old forum [thread](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2536/9849.aspx#9849) says that the wrapper uses RC4 via the Microsoft Crypto API.