# How to Encrypt a SQLite database file ".s3db"?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I am using `SQLite` database version 3 with `C#` Windows application..
i want to encrypt the SQLite database using `password` or any other encryption way in order not to enable clients to open it.
and what are the changes should be added to the `connection string` in the config file.

Comment: set password for your Sql db then remove pass from app.config file and set it problematically in your code

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1259561/1045728

Answer (score 3):

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;Password=myPassword;
```

Source: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite

Comment: how will this help from directly accessing the database?? I mean from the outside by opening it in sqlite studio or sqlite manager?