# How to encrypt a database in unity

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

please tell me how you can encrypt a database file with the extension .bytes (using Sqlite3) in Unity? I added a plugin folder to the project and added libraries:

1. System.Data.dll ,
2. Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll ,
3. sqlite3.dll ,
4. System.Configuration.dll ,
5. System.EnterpriseServices.dll ,
6. System.Security.dll.

and I put my database in a separate folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encrypt SQLite database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259561/encrypt-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @eocron, I've seen this question, but I don't understand how to set a password in unity. Do I need to create a script or what? and then where do you need to hang this script?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli